# Is Postgres Bulkloader is applicable with JNDI connection for local system

Tags: kettle, pdi

PostgreSql Bulkloader step is applicable in local system and if so is it possible to implement this step  for JNDI connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are considering your LocalSystem as a Window's Machine, it didnt work for me where the db was in a linux machine and the pentaho was in windows. It has got some issues with dual OS. Check this [issue](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?72863-Postgresql-Bulk-Loader-issues). But ideally on a windows to windows db , bulk loader step should work.

But for a Linux System, it works **fine**. I am not sure about MacOS.

For JNDI Connection: You **cannot** use a JNDI database connection since its not supported.

Please check this [link](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/PostgreSQL+Bulk+Loader).

Hope this is what you are looking for :)